# Combining multiple events in filter (or segment)

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, segment

In my datastudio dashboard I want to creat an engagement scoring for my users. I have identified that users with high engagement adhere to a few criteria and hit a few specific events.

These events are labeled EventA EventB and EventC. To measure how big this user base is I'm trying to add a filter combining them whith AND, not OR. Remember I don't want the total of hits of these events combined but just the users that hit all off these events in their lifespan.

Unfortunately this is not working and I end up with a result of 0. This shouldn't be the case as in some cases EventC can only receive hits if EventA and EventB have previously been hit.

Am I making a combination that shouldn't be possible? According to the Analytics hierarcy it should be possible (see https://donalytics.com/2016/04/24/analytics-101-hierarchy-of-users-sessions-hits/ also).

I have tried an Analytics segment as well but I run into the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I making a combination that shouldn't be possible?

Yes, the above [Filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066) (with the AND clause) will not produce any results in Google Data Studio as Filters work on a row-by-row basis. To elaborate, if the data is as follows:

```
+-------------+
| Event Label |
+-------------+
| EventA      |
| EventB      |
| EventC      |
| EventB      |
| EventA      |
| EventF      |
| EventG      |
| EventH      |
+-------------+
```

An **OR** Filter (EventA **OR** EventB **OR** EventC) would display values where any of the 3 events are present:

```
+-------------+
| Event Label |
+-------------+
| EventA      |
| EventB      |
| EventC      |
| EventB      |
| EventA      |
+-------------+
```

An **AND** Filter (EventA **AND** EventB **AND** EventC) would not display any results as each row contains a single Event, thus no results are displayed as it's not possible to have more than one event per row:

```
+-------------+
| Event Label |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
```